# Rails : know on which actions of a controller a filter/action is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I currently have the list of filters my controller can run using this code :

```
MyController._process_action_callbacks.select{
  |f| f.filter.is_a? Symbol
}.map(&:filter)
```

But I would also like to filter them on their action. I.e. something like this :

```
MyController._process_action_callbacks.select{
  |f| (f.filter.is_a?(Symbol)
  && f.actions.include?(my_action)) # filter on action
}.map(&:filter)
```

which obviously doesn't work. How can I achieve this ?

The only thing I have found is with `instance_variable_get('@if')`but this isn't really satisfying as it gives a string (I could `eval`it or parse it, but that doesn't seem idiomatic), and I also have to do it for the `unless`part.

Comment: You can use `action_name`

Comment: `Api::UsersController._process_action_callbacks.first.action_name`
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'action_name' for #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007ffdb877a930>`

Comment: Do you mean controller action?

Comment: I mean : I need to find, for each filter, what are the controller actions on which it is called

Comment: The `if`/`unless` method seems to be the only way. Unless you want to monkey patch rails.

Comment: Mind me asking what the wider scope of this is?

Comment: I want to generate parts of a documentation automatically. And for each controller action, I add error codes to the documentation depending on what filters are called before/after this action

Comment: Sounds like a tough job, lots of edge cases: `before_action :foo, if: :bar?`. The documentation for `bar?` will also be needed to be able to catch all errors. Then you have things like: `skip_before_action`. Are there no tools that do this automatically?

Comment: Don't know about other tools. In my case, I don't have those problems though. The only conditions I have are on the action.
I went with the `if/unless`